# How to fix R "expected ',' after expression" on every line?

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

At least half of my lines in my rmd contains the error of "expected ',' after expression", however the code runs perfectly fine with no issues

[image: screenshot]

I tried:

- copying and pasting the code to a new code block
- retyping the code manually instead of using copy/paste from a code cheat sheet
- updating R and Rstudio as well as packages associated with the code

I have not been able to find any related help documentation on this matter

Comment: I'm going to take a wild guess and do a search and replace that comma character with `,`. I've often found that if someone copies code from Microsoft Word or something akin to it, it will copy a weird character that looks like a comma but isn't interpreted as one. There is a similar issue with the quote characters.

Comment: happens with quotation marks too!